# ReactJs: Passing a prop and using it within a map()

Tags: django, reactjs

I'm trying to take a user inputted code and compare it to code within my database. Right now I can bring the code and display it outside the map function but when I try to add it, it doesn't work. here is my database:

```
 [
    {
        "dwelling_code": "ABC-XYZ",
        "dwelling_name": "Neves Abode",
        "has_superAdmin": true,
        "room": []
    }
```

This is the parent component:

```
    class Dwel2 extends Component {
    state = {
        house: [],
        selectedMovie: null,
        data: "ABC-XYZ"

    }
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('Removed for question', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {

        }
    }).then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(resp => this.setState({ house: resp }))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

houseClicked = h => {
    console.log(h)
}

render() {
    return <div>
        <EnterCode dataFromParent={this.state.data}
            house={this.state.house}
            houseClicked={this.house} />
    </div>
}
}
```

This is the child component:

```
    function EnterCode(props) {

    return (

        <div>

            <div>
                *THIS BIT DISPLAYS THE CODE*{props.dataFromParent}
            </div>
            {props.house.map(house => {


                var test = house.dwelling_name
                var code = house.dwelling_code
                if (code === {props.dataFromParent}) {
                    test = "Test"
                }
                return (

                    <React.Fragment>
                        <div>{test}</div>
                    </React.Fragment>

                )
            })}

        </div>
    )

}
```

I just want to compare the code in the database to the code defined in the parent component. Here is the error that's coming up this is in the child component.

```
  Line 17:31:  'dataFromParent' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting an error, added it at the bottom

Comment: That's a weird error. Does that "Line 17:31:" from the error correspond to any `props.dataFromParent` in the piece of code you added?

Comment: Yeah it's in the if statement in the child component

Comment: Now everything is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a tiny mistake in the `if` statement. You put the `props.dataFromParent` in brackets, which in the context of JSX would be required, but in the context of JS means creating an object, which is clearly wrong.

```
if (code === props.dataFromParent) {
    test = "Test"
}
```

Hope this helps :)